# How do I direct visitors to pages based on the country they're viewing from? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I am using code from the example "How could I redirect users from multiple countries to multiple pages, respectively?", a free JavaScript from [Geobytes](http://geobytes.com/GeoDirection.htm).

If a visitor from the UK or Norway is viewing my site, he is redirected to pages specifically made for those countries, but if the visitor is from any other country (Australia, USA), he is not redirected to page for those countries; [my site (under construction)](http://winappleiphone.info) remains blank.

I would like to be able to send these non-UK non-Norway users to the correct site.

My sample code:

```
 <head>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?after=-1"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    var UK="UK";
    var Norway="NO";

    if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)!="undefined")
    {
       var sCountryCode=sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2);

          if(UK.indexOf(sCountryCode)>=0)
          {
             // UK Visitors would go here
             document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://www.google.co.uk'>");
          }
          else if(Norway.indexOf(sCountryCode)>=0)
          {
             // Norway Visitors would go here

             document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://www.google.no'>");
          }



else
          {
             // World Visitors would go here
             document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://www.google.com/ncr'>");
          }
       }
  //  }
    </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: And your question is? Please provide more information... what exactly does not work? Is the issue related to `geobytes` API?

Comment: like i asked in the question if the visitor is viewing my site from the UK or Norway he is redirected to pages specifically made for those countries but if the visitor is from any other country say Austria he is not redirected to page for other countries.

Comment: So it all depends on 'geobytes' API?

Comment: I dont get it, isnt something wrong with my If-else statement?can u check that please.

Comment: As far as I understand, the statement depends on `geobytes` API. You should provide some background information. Try to debug the execution flow...

Comment: This js code is awful/weird. `if(UK.indexOf(sCountryCode)>=0)` - why isn't that `if (sCountryCode === 'UK')`.

Comment: @home: i am using a free script from http://www.geobytes.com/GeoDirection.htm i am trying to shoehorn example below the heading : ""How could I redirect users from multiple countries to multiple pages respectively?"" background information? what do you mean home? (confused)

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your case is that in your current site (winappleiphone.info), you are checking for countries with the following variables:

- UK, USA, Canada, sPhilippineLocations, sKoreanLocations, sChineseLocations

Out of these variables, **you have declared only UK and USA variables but you are trying to use the other variables without declaring them and assigning any value which results in a JavaScript error** and hence your script fails at times.

Comment: huh????...i don't think that is the case and(in the original code) i have declared 28 countries INCLUDING UK and USA.and why the IF statements don't result in any error but same line while in else results in nothing happening at all.

Comment: See, the error you are facing is as simple as checking the error console of your browser or looking at the console of Firebug (in Firefox) ... or other corresponding developer tools in other browsers.


The shortcut to open that debugging console is F12 on most browsers

You can see an error reported like: (When tested from an out of UK/US machine ... for this, you might need to use some solution like VPN for other countries)
Error: ReferenceError: Canada is not defined
Source File: http://winappleiphone.info/
Line: 46

Comment: Yeah but i did declare each and every one of those countries :(

Comment: Probably your latest file did not get uploaded ... but I hope that now you are able to find the error by looking at the error console/Firebug or other similar tool for your browser ... I suggest you to go to your site and do right click > "View Page Source" ... and compare it with the source code you have on your localhost

Comment: @OmairIqbal: As jsbookmarklets.com stated, you missed Canada. It is not defined. Look at your code. But you should really consider to use br3ts version. It's unnecessary and ugly to define all those variables and introduces a lot of redundancy to your code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
//* init location codes for redirecting
var finded = false,
    redirections = {
        UK: 'http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=3135&pub=13435&id=7547&sid=',
        US: 'http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=2907&pub=13435&id=7038&sid=',
        CA: 'French.htm',   // Canada
        PH: 'Philippine.htm',   // Philippines
        KO: 'Korean.htm',   // Korea
        CH: 'Chinese.htm'   // China
    };
//* Checking location code
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode) != "undefined")
{
    var sCountryCode = sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2);
    for(var i in redirections) {
        if(i == sCountryCode) {
            document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=" + redirections[i] + "'>");
            finded = true;
        }
    }
}
//* location code not finded - redirect to default page
if(!finded) {
    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=World.htm'>");
}
```

As you can see - I can simply add/remove new redirect-pages without copying a lot kBs of code. Some of codes I provided may be incorrect, fix it by yourself, if needed

Answer (score 3):

For the page to become white either

```
typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode) == undefined 
//It is actually undefined...
```

or

```
 sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2)
```

throws an error.

So put an else statement to handle is actually undefined case and check the length of **sGeobytesLocationCode** to determine if its length is actually **0** or **1**.

```
 if((typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)!= "undefined") && (sGeobytesLocationCode.length > 1))
 {
      //bla bla
 }
 else
 {
      //Go to default page instead of showing white
 }
```

These are the basics or else **ask the users which site they want to enter instead of showing a white page** :)

Answer (score 2):

In the case that sGeobytesLocationCode is undefined you aren't redirecting.  Also, your if else statements will start to get out of hand when you have a lot of locations you're comparing to. br3t has a good solution.  You should also make sure that sGeobytesLocationCode is a string of length 2 or greater, and cast it to uppercase (just in case).

```
    redirections = {
        UK: 'http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=3135&pub=13435&id=7547&sid=',
        US: 'http://www.adworkmedia.com/go.php?camp=2907&pub=13435&id=7038&sid=',
        CA: 'French.htm',   // Canada
        PH: 'Philippine.htm',   // Philippines
        KO: 'Korean.htm',   // Korea
        CH: 'Chinese.htm'   // China
    };
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode) === 'string' && sGeobytesLocationCode.substring.length > 1)
{
    var sCountryCode = sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2).toUpperCase();
    for(var i in redirections) {
        if(i == sCountryCode) {
            document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=" + redirections[i] + "'>");
           return;
        }
    }
}
//* location code not redirected - redirect to default page
    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=World.htm'>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic doesn't account for the case when `sGeobytesLocationCode` is undefined. Also, errors could occur when `sGeobytesLocationCode` isn't a string, or has less than two characters. The below code starts out setting a default url, which assumes the user is not in the UK or Norway. Then, this url is changed only if `sGeobytesLocationCode` passes several conditions. There is no path in which a user won't be redirected. I also added logic to check and make sure there won't be errors in `substring` and `indexOf`. In addition, the logic of redirecting only occurs in one place, instead of inside every if-else block.

```
<head>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?after=-1"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        var UK="UK";
        var Norway="NO";

        // default url, if country is not uk or norway
        var url = "http://www.google.com/ncr";

        if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode) == "string" && sGeobytesLocationCode.length >= 2)
        {
            var sCountryCode = sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2);

            if (UK.indexOf(sCountryCode) >= 0)
            {
                // UK Visitors would go here
                url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
            }
            else if (Norway.indexOf(sCountryCode) >= 0)
            {
                // Norway Visitors would go here
                url = "http://www.google.no";
            }
        }

        document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=" + url + "'>");
    </script>
</head>
```

**Note:** The code I provided uses your exact code with the couple minor changes needed to make your case work. However, your code can be written better. Consider the following:

- Not all browsers support `indexOf`. You might need to provide a
  default implementation in order to support all browsers. You can
  google this, there are several places that give the code. With that
  said, `indexOf` seems redundant in this case, since you already used
  `substring` to include only the two-letter country code. Consider
  taking out the `indexOf` and just check that the country codes are
  equal.
- To increase maintainability of your code, you might want to consider
  adding all of the country codes ("NO" and "UK" so far) and their
  corresponding urls to an array. This way you can loop through the
  array and only write a single block of code that does the comparison and
  sets the url. The way you have it now, you need an if statement with
  repeated logic for every country code you want to check for. That's not 
  so bad now, but if you plan on adding country codes in the future, it 
  will get ugly fast.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work nicely and is much more compact.

```
<head>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?after=-1"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        var countrySuffix = {
            //add more specific countries here if you want
            "UK": 'http://www.google.co.uk',
            "NO": 'http://www.google.no',
            //The default location we'll go to if we're not in any of the above
            //   locations
            "DEFAULT": 'http://www.google.com/ncr'
        };

        var sCountryCode;

        if(sGeobytesLocationCode && sGeobytesLocationCode.length > 1){
            sCountryCode = sGeobytesLocationCode.substring(0,2);
        }

        var targetSite = countrySuffix[(sCountryCode || "DEFAULT").toUpperCase()] || countrySuffix.DEFAULT;
        document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=" + targetSite + "'>");
    </script>
</head>
```